# Windows FIle Explorer, add clone clipboard contents in context menu

Tags: powershell, registry, git-clone

Also see my [Run Powershell](https://superuser.com/questions/1804902/run-powershell-command-from-cmd-with-parameters?noredirect=1#comment2830470_1804902).

My attempt is to implement the following work flow

- in GitHub or anyother repo server copy the link to a repo
- in Windows File explorer right click a folder eg `D:\Projects` to open the context menu.
- select **Clone here** from the context menu to clone the copied repo in that folder.

I added this in registry

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\git-clone]
@="Clone here"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\git-clone\command]
@="Powershell -NoProfile -Command \"git clone $(Get-Clipboard)\""
```

This does add a "Clone here" to the context menu and it clones but not in the directory right clicked but its parent directory.

How would I clone the repo in the directory right clicked?

Comment: Try `...-Command \"sl -LiteralPath '%V'; git clone ... `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @keithmiller tip I found the solution

The command that works is

```
Powershell -NoProfile -Command "Set-Location -LiteralPath '%V' ; git clone $(Get-Clipboard)"
```

And the registry entry can be created with the following `.reg` file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\git-clone]
@="Clone here"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\git-clone\command]
@="Powershell -NoProfile -Command \"Set-Location -LiteralPath '%V' ; git clone $(Get-Clipboard)\""
```

I use Directory branch instead of Folder here as it probably only works in real file directories.